# Find $\lim\limits_{n→∞}\left(t+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How would one go about finding the limit of $\displaystyle \left(|t|+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$? ($t$ and $x$ are both positive.)

Of course $\displaystyle \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ has limit $e^x$, but how would this help?

Comment: Of course, $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ is not $e^n.$ Moreover, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}=e.$

Comment: Do you need to use the absolute value if you're specifying $t>0$?

For $t > 1$, the limit is infinite:

$$
\left(t + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n \geq t^n + \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^n \to \infty
$$

Comment: sorry m strochyk I totally forgot that for but I see.

Comment: Yes you do need to use the absolute value of t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:
$$\lim\limits_{n→∞}\left(1+\frac{Q}{n}\right)^n=e^Q$$
**So you have**:
$$\lim\limits_{n→∞}\left(t+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=\lim\limits_{n→∞}\left(1+\frac{{x\over t}}{n}\right)^n*t^n=e^{x\over t}*t^n$$

**The limit is**:
∞ if $t>1$
 0 if $t<1$
$e^{x\over t}$ if $t=1$

Comment: yes because x^n if x>0 then it would be infinity

Comment: I think this makes sense Rnjai but hmm would you not get e^x times t^n like this

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: one thing I am not sure is how you get y=x/t I understand it up till that part

Comment: There-You dont have any "y" now.

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense now thanks